# telerik controls in .html page

Tags: html, telerik

I'm currently editing a .html file with telerik radtooltips hooked up to a mapped image. Basically there are small blocks on the image that have been set to fire the radtooltips on mouse over. The html file is ran inside of a .aspx file and it inherits the telerik namespace. However, I cannot set attributes in the radtooltips and it instead defaults to a really ugly default style that I can no longer change. I've also tried setting up divs and tables inside the tool tip however, the tooltip container isn't affected so you get a nasty yellow border from the tooltip around whatever definitions are setup for the table or div.
Example:
[image: The ugly tooltip I cannot edit] 
The orange background is defined by a div inside the tooltip:

```
<div style="background-color:Orange; border-color:#b24710;">
```

This is the current tooltip I have defined...and the attributes that are being ignored:

```
<telerik:RadToolTip ID="rttGeochemTip" runat="server" TargetControlID="geochem" RelativeTo="Mouse"
                        Position="BottomCenter" BackColor="Gray" BorderColor="Black" Font="Sans-serif">
```

I have also tried this without the nested div:

```
<telerik:RadToolTip ID="rttCharTechTip" runat="server" TargetControlID="char" RelativeTo="Mouse"
                        Position="BottomCenter" BackColor="Gray" BorderColor="Black" Font="Sans-serif">
```

the code above without the nested div is the same as the screenshot except for the orange is replaced by that default yellow border color because I'm not overriding the inside color. I have also tried using CSS to the same failed effects.

Any ideas of what might cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html page was nested inside a .aspx page and some how the inheritance of the telerik skin sunset was being applied and I wasn't able to override it. To fix the problem I ended up adding in a telerik skinmanager and applied a more appropriate skin for my controls and that fixed the issue. I'm assuming our styling setup wasn't built to the telerik skin standards.